# WebDriverManager take incorrect version of driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to run the selenium script through the docker which is installing the chrome browser using following command:

```
RUN dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome \
    && echo "#!/bin/bash\nexec /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.real --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox \"\$@\"" > /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome \
    && chmod 755 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

the above command is installing the chrome browser version 84:

```
Setting up google-chrome-stable (84.0.4147.89-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
```

but the WebDriverManager is installing the driver version 85:

```
 10 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Please answer the following questionnaire based on your experience with WebDriverManager. Thanks a lot!
10 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - ====> XXXXXXX.cc/wdm-survey <====
876 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek chromedriver
1825 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader - Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.38/chromedriver_linux64.zip
4148 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader - Extracting binary from compressed file chromedriver_linux64.zip
6296 [TestNG-test=StructurePhoto-1] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /root/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/85.0.4183.38/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}) on port 24023
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Because of above version miss-match the scripts are failing.
i am using the dependency:

```
<dependency>
             <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
             <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
             <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong can someone please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below line, where you can specify the version number.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("84").setup();
```

Comment: if I use fix version it will create problem when version gets updated....also i am running same selenium script on windows machine where the chrome version is 83....so i don't want to use the fix version of WebDriverManager.

Comment: Yes, that's a know limitation. But, have you tried with 4.1.0 version?

Comment: I have tried with WebDriverManager version-4.1.0 but still getting the same issue.