# Are there any side-effects of using maven dependency - WebDriverManager from bonigarcia?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

*WebDriverManager from bonigarcia* https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager is available as a dependency in maven repository. This helps to avoid manual downloads of chromedriver.exe and setting it's path in the code. We are trying to decide whether to implement this in our project.

Any insights on possible side-effects or issues using this dependency would be helpful. I couldn't find much information on this online.

Comment: Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074312/webdrivermanager-take-incorrect-version-of-driver-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Side effect is that your code will have to access external network resources. This might be an issue especially when you work within corporate networks.

If this will be the case, you might face the restrictions and will have configure your local repository and maintain the versions within that repository manually.